# Window Location with Set Time out

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I Have to delay my redirection by few seconds. When I try to do this It is not working. I have attached my Javascript and php below. can anyone please help me to solve the problem.window location not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // constants to define the title of the alert and button text.
var ALERT_TITLE = "Answer";
var ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT = "Ok";

// over-ride the alert method only if this a newer browser.
// Older browser will see standard alerts
if(document.getElementById) {
    window.alert = function(txt) {
        createCustomAlert(txt);
    }
}

function createCustomAlert(txt) {
    // shortcut reference to the document object
    d = document;

    // if the modalContainer object already exists in the DOM, bail out.
    if(d.getElementById("modalContainer")) return;

    // create the modalContainer div as a child of the BODY element
    mObj = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    mObj.id = "modalContainer";
     // make sure its as tall as it needs to be to overlay all the content on the page
    mObj.style.height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight + "px";

    // create the DIV that will be the alert 
    alertObj = mObj.appendChild(d.createElement("div"));
    alertObj.id = "alertBox";
    // MSIE doesnt treat position:fixed correctly, so this compensates for positioning the alert
    if(d.all && !window.opera) alertObj.style.top = document.documentElement.scrollTop + "px";
    // center the alert box
    alertObj.style.left = (d.documentElement.scrollWidth - alertObj.offsetWidth)/2 + "px";

    // create an H1 element as the title bar
    h1 = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("h1"));
    h1.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_TITLE));

    // create a paragraph element to contain the txt argument
    msg = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("p"));
    msg.innerHTML = txt;

    // create an anchor element to use as the confirmation button.
    btn = alertObj.appendChild(d.createElement("a"));
    btn.id = "closeBtn";
    btn.appendChild(d.createTextNode(ALERT_BUTTON_TEXT));
    btn.href = "#";
    // set up the onclick event to remove the alert when the anchor is clicked
    btn.onclick = function() { removeCustomAlert();return false; }


}

// removes the custom alert from the DOM
function removeCustomAlert() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].removeChild(document.getElementById("modalContainer"));
}

   function handler(var1,quizId,isCorrect,score) {
        alert(var1);
        //var id = parseInt(quizId);
        quizId++;
        var points=10;      
        if(isCorrect=='true'){
            score=score+points;
            var string_url="quiz.php?qusId="+quizId+"&score="+score;
            setTimeout('window.location =string_url',5000) ;
        }
        else{
            var string_url="quiz.php?qusId="+quizId+"&score="+score;
            setTimeout('window.location =string_url',5000) ;
            }


    }

  </script>
```

---

```
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){

    ?><input type="radio" name="answers" value="<?php echo $row1['answers'];?>"  onclick="handler('<?php echo $row1["feedback"]; ?>',<?php echo $qusId;?>,'<?php echo $row1["isCorrect"]; ?>',<?php echo $score;?>)
"/ ><?php echo $row1['answers']; ?><br/>







<?php 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of setTimeout should be a function. Try wrapping it with an anonymous function like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = string_url
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
`setTimeout("createCustomAlert(txt);", 3000);`
```